# Is there a way to make the output file of a stream:file?fileName= dynamic?

Tags: apache-camel

Given a simple route like this

```
route.from("direct:foo")
   .split()
   .tokenize("\n")
   .streaming()
   .to("stream:file?fileName=target/streaming${header.count}.txt&closeOnDone=true");
```

which I then trigger with this

```
@Test
public void splitAndStreamToFile() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        builder.append(i);
        builder.append("\n");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        template.sendBodyAndHeader(builder.toString(), "count", i);
    }

}
```

I get one big file that contains 10 times 500 lines, where I would have hoped to have 10 files that contain 500 lines each.

In other words, it seems that the fileName in the stream:file endpoint is not dynamic. I am wondering if this is at all possible? My google-fu turned up nothing so far.

EDIT:

With Claus' answer, I got it to work like this:

```
route.from("direct:foo")
                    .split()
                    .tokenize("\n")
                    .streaming()
                    .recipientList(route.simple("stream:file?fileName=target/streaming${header.count}.txt&closeOnDone=true"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a *dynamic to* which there is an EIP pattern for:

- http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

But it could be a good idea to support the file/simple language on the fileName option as the regular file component does. Fell free to log a JIRA ticket about this improvement.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still new to Camel so I wasn't aware I could get it to work that way.

Answer (score 1):

Sourcecode of the `StreamProducer` looks like it does not support any of the expression languages of Camel yet:

```
private OutputStream resolveStreamFromFile() throws IOException {
    String fileName = endpoint.getFileName();
    ObjectHelper.notEmpty(fileName, "fileName");
    LOG.debug("About to write to file: {}", fileName);
    File f = new File(fileName);
    // will create a new file if missing or append to existing
    f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    f.createNewFile();
    return new FileOutputStream(f, true);
}
```

See [sourecode](https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/camel-git/components/camel-stream/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/stream/StreamProducer.java?hb=true#to96).

If you need dynamic filenames, you should take a look at the [file component](https://camel.apache.org/file2.html), which supports the [file language](https://camel.apache.org/file-language.html) and the `CamelFileName` header.

Answer (score 0):

In short,

to**D** `uri=stream:file...`

will do it.

The "to**D**" basically translates the "`simple`" or "`file language`" before it hits the stream component code...so that works for `"fileName=..."`